# Why should we use 'for' before authority in this case?

Tags: prepositions, usage

This was one of our questions in our practice book:

> #### Fill in the blank using a suitable preposition:
>
> Students today do not have respect ______ authority.

I think the most suitable preposition would be *to*, but the answer given in the book was *for*.

Why?

Comment: Prepositions are tricky. The book is correct however, *respect for something* is the idiomatic usage.

Comment: The only real answer for most questions about why prepositions are the way they are is "Because English is like that."  You *have respect* **for**  someone or something - that's just the way it is.

Comment: @stangdon I agree.  I could suggest some odd cases where *respect to authority* would be fine, but I don't want to muddy the waters of what is a perfectly good answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*{verb} to X* "aims" the action of a verb toward X.

This doesn't have sense with *have X* in the sense of *possess X*, because the action of possession can be aimed/targeted toward what you are trying to take, but not anything else.  Saying "I possess the ball to John" doesn't work, for example.

*For X* works because a meaning of for is not to express what you are targeting in an action but instead expresses the owner, reason, or purpose, or an object that is involved in being the owner, reason or purpose.  "I possess the ball for John" works (John is the reason why I'm keeping the ball, maybe he asked me to hold it).

Answer (score 1):

OP is getting confused between two (three?) different idiomatic usages...

> 1: *I **have respect for** the law...*
>    2a: *...but [**with respect to**](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/with+respect+to) sexual orientation I think that's a personal matter...*
>    2b: *...but [**in respect of**](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/in-respect-of-sth) sexual orientation I think that's a personal matter*

Comment: Might I respectfully suggest rather 'Students today do not show any respect _to_ authority.

Comment: No, @EdwinAshworth, I think that's a red herring. _To_ goes with _show_ there, not with _respect_.

Comment: @Colin Fine The exercise is to try to pinpoint the source of OP's misconceptions.

Comment: @Edwin, Colin: I accept that ***show** respect **to** authority* [does in fact occur](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=show+respect+to+authority%2Cshow+respect+for+authority&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cshow%20respect%20to%20authority%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cshow%20respect%20for%20authority%3B%2Cc0). But it's far less common than *show respect **for** authority* anyway - AND **to** is virtually unknown in the form ***have** respect **to** authority*, where it's invariably ***for***.

Comment: I'm suggesting (strongly) that the common three-word string 'show respect to' is quite likely to be informing OP's attraction to the choice of 'to'.

Comment: @Edwin: Yeah, sorry. I do actually understand the point you're making (Heck! I even *agree* with it!). But the truth is although I find *show + to* at least "acceptable", I'm definitely with the majority in significantly preferring *show + for*. The fact that I find *have + to* more or less *totally* unacceptable makes me feel that learners would be better off not even *trying* to assimilate *show + to* - but if you posted an answer focusing on exactly *why* OP "got it wrong", I'd probably upvote it.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: Right, I understand the point you're making now, which I didn't at first.

Comment: @FF I'm only here because I took a wrong turn somewhere. I'm supposed to be getting directions for a walk in the Peak District. Doesn't look promising.